# Image not being set in the UItableViewCell:

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata, sdwebimage

I am trying to set an image to the UITAbleViewCell but it does not show up untill unless scrolled.

I apologize if its repetitive. But I've tried setNeedsDiplay, reloadRowsinIndexPAth, and all other reload methods. I am using SDWebImageCache to download the image and [RayWenderlich's example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2) to create horizontal Tableviewcells. I am pasting my code for your reference.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ArticleCell";
__block ArticleCell_iPad *cell = (ArticleCell_iPad *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[ArticleCell_iPad alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kCellWidth_iPad, kCellHeight_iPad)];
}
if ([self.articles count] == 0) {
    return cell;
}
__block Offer *offer = [self.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 201, 201)];
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", offer.image.url]];
    [imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [cell.thumbnail setImage:imageView.image];
        cell.titleLabel.text = offer.title;
        cell.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", offer.regularprice];
    });
});
dispatch_release(concurrentQueue);
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is imageView a custom UIImageView? If yes, change its name, or the cell will use the UITableViewCell's imageView

Comment: I changed the name, still didnt work. Do yu see anything else going wrong in the code?? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Everything related to UI need to be processed inside of main thread so place the

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL];
```

this code to inside of the dispatch_get_main_queue() block.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for your response. I've tried that too. Still no good.
SDWebImageCache said in one of their blogs to use a placeholder image.
Even that didnt work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

I got rid of the intermediate UIImageview. Setting the image directly to the thumbnail did the trick.